# Some questions about mopub and networks. Very confused

Tags: android, ads, adview, mopub

First of all, how do I add a network to mopub? I am stuck at this screen. What do I do from here to add Millenial Media as a network?

Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSouu.png

Secondly, both Millenial Media and mopub asks for payment info. Who is going to pay me? Are they both? Will millenial media know that Im using mopub and pay mopub to pay me?

Thirdly, will adding more networks lead to more income? What is the correlation? Do I even need to add networks to display ads? Will mopub choose automatically from which network it will display ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across this recently.

The screenshot you've got there is exactly what I was getting, It can be solved by disabling your browser Ad block (I use AdBlock), there should be a load of info there and fields to fill in but with AdBlock or similar active it blocks them!

Secondly, MoPub is like a wrapper for ads. You pick a network, such as AdMob, then enter that info intpo MoPub, and MoPub will display AdMob's ads.

MoPub is largely for use with engines such as Construct 2 where there is no low-level or SDK integration.